# About localization and integral closure

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Given domain $R$ and $\frac{a}{b}\in frac(R)$, suppose $\frac{a}{b}$ is integral over $R_\frak{m}$ for any maximal ideal ${\frak m}$ of $R$. Then is it right that $\frac{a}{b}$ is integral over $R$?

I know that $R$ is integral closed if and only if each localization w.r.t. a maximal ideal is integral closed. Can I solve my problem by this assertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $R$, and suppose $x \in K$ is integral over each localization $R_{\mathfrak m}$.  Let

$$I = \{ r \in R : rx \textrm{ is integral over } R \}$$

Then $I$ is an ideal of $R$.  If we can show that

$$I_{\mathfrak m} = \{r \in R_{\mathfrak m} : rx \textrm{ is integral over } R_{\mathfrak m}\}$$

then we will have $I_{\mathfrak m} = R_{\mathfrak m}$ for all $\mathfrak m$, hence $I = R$.

Comment: (I haven't checked that the right hand side is contained in $I_{\mathfrak m}$)